# Why my QR Code Generator only show one value

Tags: xcode, swiftui, qr-code

I have a project need to create qr code generator and i want to show more than one value when customer insert their information.
My Qr Code generator have some information field to let customer insert their infomation, but i added these field and test out, it only show one value, and i don' know why other values didn't show, maybe i just missed some part in the code, i don't know where is the problem, any expert knows what happened?

Example of the Code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct GenerateQRCode: View {
    @State var first = "D3"
    @State var id = "abcafewrqr
    @Binding var time: Date"
    
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return df
    }
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Image(uiImage: GenerateTime(first: first, id: id, time: time))
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func GenerateTime(first: String, id: String, time: Date)-> UIImage {
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: time)
        let all = first + id + str
        let com = all.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(com, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

Update:

```
func GenerateTime(first: String, id: String, time: Date)-> UIImage {
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: time)
        let timeData = str.data(using: .utf8)
        let idData = id.data(using: .utf8)
        let firstData = first.data(using: .utf8)
        let com = firstData, idData, TimeData              //<--Here Updated
        filter.setValue(com, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
```

CombineString like above what i did, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you get only one date from the 3 dates you've set in the QR code generator when scanning the resulting QR code?

If yes, then here is your problem:

```
filter.setValue(firstData, forKey: "inputMessage")
filter.setValue(idData, forKey: "inputMessage") 
filter.setValue(timeData, forKey: "inputMessage")
```

You are suppose to set `inputMessage` once. Each subsequent `setValue` call will overwrite the previous.

You should format the 3 dates into one `String` and set `inputMessage` only once.

Comment: I think you are right for my problem, it should be 3 datas into one string write into ```filter.setValue(....```, I don't how to write into 3 datas into one string, do you have any example could show me to understand easily?

Comment: Just do `let combinedString = "You can add anything in front of the strings \(string1) and in between \(string2) and same here \(string3) or even after."

Comment: But I have tried in the function with combinestring and it doesn't work it said **Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to two 'Data?' operands**

Comment: You need to put the string together *before* you convert it to Data. My example again: `let combinedString = "You can add anything in front of the strings (string1) and in between (string2) and same here (string3) or even after."` Only after creating the combinedString, you convert it to Data.

Comment: but i have date variable type in the combine string, it will still works?

Comment: this error shows up when i typed `let all = first + id + time` **Cannot use instance member 'first' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

Comment: Look at my example instead of joining the strings with "+". You need to convert your Date object to string before you combine with the first two strings.

Comment: i have convert my date object to string in the function

Comment: Yes you have converted the time to string buy you then convert them all to Data and combine. You need to combine them before you convert the combined string to Data. I'm not sure how much more clearer I can get.

Comment: I get it now, i just confused my coding, because i just put it on the wrong place, it should be place the code `convert all to string` before `convert string to data` Thank you